# Merging two different csv with python

Tags: python

So I have one csv with 'films' in a database that have a unique ID

```
movie_title      | ID       | popularity
spider-man        unique ID   4.2
captain marvel    unique ID   9.9
```

Then about every week, I would like to update that popularity with a new one from another list of movies.

New movie list:

```
movie_title      | ID       | popularity
spider-man        unique ID   5.5
captain marvel    unique ID   7.4
```

How can I merge these two csv and output a new csv with only the value popularity updating? I have other values that also change over the week, but I just did popularity for simplicity. The unique ID must be in the new csv as well not only the changes; because, when I resubmit back to the database that is the only way that it will update with the ID.

The second list does not contain the ID's.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a [pandas.DataFrame.update](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html).

Use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read the csv file to a Pandas DataFrame, then do the update. Once you have made the update you can use [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to convert it back to a csv.